# how to force a line break inside a textarea?

Tags: html, textarea, line-breaks

I want to force a line break inside the textarea like this `<textarea>hello!\nbye<br>hello again\r\n i'm here</textarea>`
but this way the page only shows like this: `hello!\nbye<br>hello again\r\n i'm here`
and it should appear something like:

```
bye
hello again
I'm here
```

it's something like `&nbsp`?
which element should i use to make this line break?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <textarea id="message">Hello</textarea>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      const message = document.getElementById('message');

message.value = 'bye' + '\r\n' + 'hello again' + '\r\n' + 'Im here';

console.log(message.value);
    </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A literal new line.

```html
<textarea>bye
hello again
I'm here</textarea>
```